# how to direct user to their respective screen using firestore when they get logged in,in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have developed a sign up system in my app using firestore in Flutter where user's data can be retrieved from database with following method:

```
//get user's data from firestore


 Future<String?> getUser(String email) async {
    try {
      CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
      final snapshot = await users.doc(email).get();
      final data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return data['person_identity'];
    } catch (e) {
      return 'Error fetching user';
    }
  }
```

Now what i want? when a user logs in, based on their identity i want to direct them to their page, like if they are student, take them to **StudentScreen** else to **TeacherScreen**

how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your firebase Collection --> document of each user, I presume you have a field called type or role (e.g. Name:"luke", personal_identity:Student).

When Fetching your user data check if that **personal_identity**(user) is a  Student or a Teacher.
then navigate as per your application route.

Global variable

```
String? userType = "";
```

```
//get user data and store the personal Identity to the variable userType.
Future<void> getUser(String email) async {
try {
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  final snapshot = await users.doc(email).get();
  final data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  userType = data['person_identity']
} catch (e) {
  return 'Error fetching user';
}
```

get the data and store the type in a variable userTypeInternal

```
Future<void> signIn(String userTypeFromFIrebase) async {
  try {
    var navContext = Navigator.of(context);

    // Check if user exists
    bool userExists = false;
    final userTypeInternal = userTypeFromFIrebase ;
    UserCredential userCredential =
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email.toLowerCase().trim(),
      password: password.trim(),
    );
    userExists = userCredential.user != null;

    // Navigate to the home screen of choice if user exists
    if (userExists = userCredential.user != null && 
       userTypeInternal=="Student") {
      //this is where you implement moving to the screen
      navContext.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/studentScreen', (route) => 
  false);
    } else if (userExists = userCredential.user != null && 
       userTypeInternal=="Teacher") {
      //this is where you implement moving to the screen
      navContext.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/TeacherScreen', (route) => 
  false);
    }
  else if (!userExists) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          msg: "email doesn't exist",
          textColor: Colors.white);
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          msg: "Email account not registered",
          textColor: Colors.white);
    }
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code != 'user-not-found') {
    //flutter toast message
      Reuse.callSnack(
        context,
        "Email not registered",
      );
    
      return;
    } else if (e.code != 'wrong-password') {
      Reuse.callSnack(context, "Wrong password");
    
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle other types of errors
    switch (error) {
      case 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL':
      case 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD':
      case 'ERROR_USER_DISABLED':
      case 'ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS':
      case 'ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED':
        Reuse.callSnack(context, error.toString());
        break;
      default:
        Reuse.callSnack(context, 'An unknown error occurred');

        break;
    }
  }
}
```